# Changing content offset

Tags: ios4

On a button click I am adding images to scrollview.My requirement is to show only some portion of those images as they large in width compared to screensize.so what I am doing is changing the scrollview contentoffset.Since, I want the transition to be smooth I am using animation block.But unfortunately animation block doesnot works.content offset chnage is not smooth.Please help!

Answer (score 1):

scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```